# Losing pagination on remote data for Material Table React

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm having difficulties to display rest service data on Material Table. Table rerenders each time I make a periodic refresh, so it is impossible for the user to see the table page s/he is on after refreshes. Is there a way to save the current page in state and pass it to the table?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use local storage to store something via `useEffect`

---

```
   import React, {useState, useEffect} from `react`

   function App(){
         // string === "hello" if there is no localStorage
        const [ string, setString ] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('string') || 'hello');

        useEffect(()=> window.localStorage.setItem('string', string), [string]);

        return <button onClick={()=> setString('world')}> {string}</button>

   }
```

---

At first render `string === 'hello'`, and so it will be set to local storage by first run of `useEffect`.

Clicking on the button, `string === 'world'` and `useEffect` triggered by the change of `string` store the new value at local storage.

After refresh, `useState` will be set `string === 'world'` at mount